# Running k6 script with multiple vusers fails with "request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)" error

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, k6

My following k6 script runs fine with 1 vuser. But whenever I run with more than 1 vusers, script fails:-

> (←[33mWARN←[0m[0114] Request Failed ←[33merror←[0m="Post http://myurl.mycompany.com/v1/Order: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)").

See script below. Any help will be appreciated.

```
// Auto-generated by the Load Impact converter

import http from "k6/http";
import { check, group, sleep} from "k6";

export let options = {
  vus: 2,
  duration: "120s",
//  maxRedirects: 4
}

export default function() {
    let res;
    res = http.post("http://myurl.mycompany.com.com/v1/Order",
      "{    \"orderNumber\": \"\",  \"webConfirmationId\": 12345,   \"opptunityNum\": \"201707-861215\",    \"accountNumber\": \"GNUF4240\",    \"CustomerInstructions\": \"\", \"internalComments\": [     {           \"text\": \"Client Contact: John D johnd@mycompany.com 2125555555 \"        }   ],  \"OrderContact\": \"\", \"SalesForceContactId\": \"\",  \"ancillaryItems\": [       {           \"ancillaryItemTypeCode\": \"DISCOUNT\",            \"description\": \"2% Web Discount\",           \"unitPrice\": -4.99,           \"quantity\": 1.0       }   ],  \"billToAddress\": {},  \"CampaignNumber\": \"ZXYCR\",  \"ChargeLogicReferenceNumber\": \"\",   \"createDate\": \"2017-07-26T20:19:54.587Z\",   \"CON\": \"\",  \"orderTypeCode\": \"4XD\"  }",
      { headers: { "Authorization" : "bearer jahhHodoUVVTKqhsypd_tWbcsk", "Content-Type" : "application/json" } });
    check(res, {
      "is status 200":(r)=>r.status===200
    });
    sleep(3);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not something on your side, i.e. the server side, that causes this?  From what I can see, it looks like you want to test an ecommerce application and your k6 script will look to that site like one single user/account sending multiple identical versions of the same order, at the same time. Might well cause some confusion for the ecommerce engine on the other side, I bet. Or it may be some caching system that gets confused and prevents copies of the same transaction from getting through, perhaps.

Comment: You are correct. That was coming from db server (table lock), though the error message had no indication of that. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The response code should be 201 because it's a create action, due to it being a POST request.